# Image of Hard Drive for replication to laboratory computers

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

We have a laboratory of 100 systems where the same set of software is to be installed. Some of the systems may have different capacities of HDDs (i.e. 320 GB, 500 GB, 1 TB).

I have the following question regarding this (command specific answers required):

1. What process is to be taken to create the image of the HDD's?
2. Can that image be used to create a network based booting system? If yes, what are the network requirements?
3. Do the sizes of the HDD have to be same for creating and cloning the systems?

Comment: This should get you started: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto. Please come back with more concrete questions after that.

Answer (score 0):

Question #1 = You will need to pick a backup/restore tool. Sector based tools like "Clonezilla" will create an image that is larger but it will not require any additional steps for deployment because it can have the bootloader information included in the image. Just backup, restore to the new system, and boot it up. However in order to deploy a sector based image most programs will require you to have an equal too or larger disk than what the image was made from. You can get around this by creating partition only backups, but then your mbr or efi loaders may not be imaged depending on what tool you use. Alternatively you can use a file based backup tool like "squashfs-tools" the image will be small and faster to make, but you will need to install grub afterwards through the aid of a livecd.

Question #2 = I'll leave that to someone else to answer.

Question #3 = The sizes only need to be the same or greater if you are using a full hard drive sector based image. If you are using a partition sector based image the partition will need to be the same size or greater. If you are using a file based image then you only need enough free space to fit the data.

The easiest way would be to setup the machine that has the smallest hard drive, create a sector based hard drive image using clonezilla, and then deploy to the larger machines.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm, if I were presented by this particular problem, I would google on how to use a network bootloader to load a boot image off a networked drive, to then have the machines boot over the network.

As for the requirements, you will need standard LAN cards, Cat5 or Cat5e cable, a high speed switch at each floor node (assuming you have a server room located somewhere in the building), you will need a set of instructions on BIOS settings as you will likey have a mix of BIOS types and versions, you may need to flash a few with the latest or last BIOS images.

All this is available by googling it.